# Web2py 'Unique' constraint still being enforced after set to false

Tags: web2py

I am very new to web2py and I cannot figure out why my code is generating a ticket, can someone please help?

Originally I had set 'unique' to true for job_title but my use case for the now requires duplicates to be allowed. I changed the 'unique' constraint to false but now duplicate job titles generate a ticket.

Here is an example of the ticket i get.

```
Ticket ID
70.214.83.98.2016-07-13.22-35-40.452ce905-fbd9-4ecb-b830-04be06fc0d7a

<class 'sqlite3.IntegrityError'> UNIQUE constraint failed: job.job_title

Version
web2py™ Version 2.14.5-stable+timestamp.2016.04.14.03.26.16
Python  Python 2.7.6: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi (prefix: /usr)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kramer52/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
exec ccode in environment
  File "/home/kramer52/web2py/applications/Jobs_test/controllers/appadmin.py", line 703, in <module>
  File "/home/kramer52/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 417, in <lambda>
self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/home/kramer52/web2py/applications/Jobs_test/controllers/appadmin.py", line 151, in insert
if form.accepts(request.vars, session):
  File "/home/kramer52/web2py/gluon/sqlhtml.py", line 1746, in accepts
self.vars.id = self.table.insert(**fields)
  File "/home/kramer52/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/objects.py", line 726, in insert
ret = self._db._adapter.insert(self, self._listify(fields))
  File "/home/kramer52/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 746, in insert
raise e
IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: job.job_title
```

And here is my table definition:

```
db.define_table('job',
            Field('job_title', length=200, unique=False, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY() ),
            Field('job_department', 'reference department'),
            Field('job_flsa_status', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Exempt', 'Non-Exempt'], zero=None) ),
            Field('job_pay_type', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Hourly', 'Salaried'], zero=None) ),
            Field('job_salary_low', 'decimal(10,2)', label='Salary (low)'),
            Field('job_salary_high', type='decimal(10,2)', label='Salary (High)'),
            Field('job_summary', type='text'),
            Field('job_years_requirement', 'integer', requires=IS_INT_IN_RANGE(0, 50), default=5, label='Years Required'),
            Field('job_education_requirement', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Some HS', 'HS Diploma', 'Some College','Associates Degree','College Degree B.A.', 'College Degree B.S.', 'Masters Degree'], zero=None), label='Education' ),
            Field('job_education_requirement_required', 'boolean', default=False, label='Required?'),
            auth.signature)
```

Previously I had set unique=true for job_title and format='%(job_title)s' for the job table, I have since removed 'format'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all databases support dropping constraints (e.g., SQLite), so if you set `unique=True` when the DAL initially creates the table, later setting `unique=False` will have no effect. Instead, you will have to use some other means to drop the constraint (or in the case of SQLite, export the data, drop and re-create the entire table, and then import the saved data).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I should have stated it is a MYSQL database, but I dropped the table, recreated and inserted the data and it worked out just fine.  Common sense, I know, but thank you anyways.  Not sure how it could be MYSQL but I am getting a sql lite error....  that IS puzzling.